# Clean panda's data frame using english character

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

I have a data frame like -

```
page_no                                         text
22                   ['', 'How often should you calibrate?The question isnâ€™t whether to calibrate, itâ€™s how often to?
32                    ['', "Document(s):5128A RHapid-CalÂ® Humidity Generator Brochure 
75                   ['', " (4.32 MB)5128A ãƒ©ãƒ”ãƒ‰ã
```

I need the data frame looks like -

```
page_no                                         text
22                   'How often should you calibrate?The question isnt whether to calibrate, its how often to?
32                    "Document(s):5128A RHapid-Cal Humidity Generator Brochure 
75                   "(4.32 MB)5128A
```

Mainly wants to remove 1st three letters from the data frame and unwanted character like - ãƒ©ãƒ”ãƒ‰ã.

I have done the following code -

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str[3:]
```

But unable to remove the junk value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes all non-ASCII characters (e.g. "ã", "ƒ" etc.)

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x[1].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to replace all non-ascii chars with nothing:

```
df['text'] = re.sub(r'[^ -~]', '', df['text'])
```